# Semantic UI dropdown always returns null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI for an ASP.NET core project and I'm trying to submit a form that has a drop down inside it but it always returns null. It's not really documented anywhere.

```
    <div class="field">
        <label>Producer</label>
        <select class="ui search dropdown" asp-for="Producer">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Producer>)ViewData["Producers"])
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
```

And the controller (even though it doesn't rally matter here):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult NewProduct(Product product)
{
    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product));
}
```

Everything else works fine in my form but `select`.

Comment: Can you include the code for the Product class ?

Answer (score 0):

You missed tag `name`

```
<select class="ui search dropdown" name="my_select" asp-for="Producer">
```